# Start Activity in onLoadFinished method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have `DialogFragment` and a `Loader`.

Dialog prompts user to logout from Application.

When user chooses to logout I fire `Loader` which clears the preferences and database and then I finish current `Activity`.

After `Loader` is finished I would like to start a new `Activity` with login screen, but I encounter two problems:

1. `getActivity()` method returns `null`
2. I'm not able to run new `Activity` because I'm out of `Activity` `context`

Do You have any solutions for this?

Comment: So, in `onLoadFinished` you call `startActivity` for your "Login" `Activity` and `finish` for the current `FragmentActivity` holding your `Fragment(s)`. Is that right?

Comment: I feel your problem is by calling finish. I beleive doing so destroys your activity references. This making getActivity() return null. Perhaps you can move to a more event driven style and have a broadcast intent generated once the user chooses to log out. Then have a receiver in your login screen activity to wake itself up.

Comment: @RyanGray Even though I don't call finish reference to `Activity` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like your situation warrants the use of a `Loader` or the `LoaderManager` at all.

1. Use an `AsyncTask` to clear the preferences and database (perhaps showing a `ProgressDialog` of some sorts if this operation is time-consuming).
2. When the task is complete, `onPostExecute` is called. Write a callback method from the fragment to the activity which will first call `startActivity(...)` and then call `finish()`.

Comment: Sounds legit. I have only one doubt - what if `Activity` would get recreated (eg. configuration change)? I would end up calling callback on the old `Activity` instance while the new one won't be affected.

Comment: As long as you are showing your dialog after `onActivityCreated` is called, you know that the underlying Activity has to exist.

Comment: @pixel btw, the reason why you are getting an error is probably because you are attempting to perform a Fragment transaction in `onLoadFinished`. The documentation specifically states you shouldn't do this in `onLoadFinished` since the `Activity`'s state may not be saved. Nonetheless, I would still suggest you use an `AsyncTask` here.

Comment: Now I'm firing `AsyncTask` in `onClick` method in `DialogFragment`. OnClick method dismisses `DialogFragment` and runs `AsyncTask`. But during `doInBackground` Activity can be killed and recreated, so I won't be able to use callback.

Comment: You can wrap your `AsyncTask` in a `Fragment` and have your `Fragment` retain its state across configuration changes by calling `setRetainInstance(true)` on it. This is the preferred method of retaining an `AsyncTask` across configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the intent again:

```
final Context context = this;

//load next activity by intent
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class); 
//use the YourActivity activity project
startActivity(intent);
```